# ISNULL IN SQL QUERY

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, vb.net, stored-procedures

Im stuck in returning of `ISNULL` it is always `sample 3`

Is this is correct?

```
SELECT
  Text1, Text2, ISNULL(ISNULL(Sample1,Sample2), Description) as Text3
WHERE
  . . .
```

My Data in records `Sample1` and `Sample2`

```
Sample1 | Sample2
a       | Null ---
Null    | b ---
Null    | Null ---
Null    | Null ---
```

Can some on help me? I can't find some problem that is related in my problem.

Comment: Do you perhaps want `COALESCE(Sample1, Sample2, Description)`?

Comment: COALESCE seems to be the correct way for your task. However you are confusing ISNULL with IFNULL, the first takes only one argument

Comment: @jarlh tnx.....

Comment: @Steve tnx.....

Comment: by using your query, i can return a or b when one of them is not null instead of sample 3. i think you may need to check the input dataset

Comment: @SKLTFZ yah you're right. But now I know that `coalesce` will simplify my code, rather than using `ISNULL` many time. The output of the two are the same but ithink `coalesce` is the proper syntax to use if the scenario is like that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use from query :

`SELECT Text1, Text2,  COALESCE (Sample1,Sample2), Description) as Text3;`

This is the correct query.

Comment: I dont think if that is correct but i'm using `COALESCE(Sample1, Sample2, Description)` and it is working fine